# 32-bit libraries GCC for RHEL/CentOS 7

Tags: rhel, gcc, libraries, 32bit, compatibility

```
yum groupinstall "Compatibility Libraries"

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
There is no installed groups file.
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Warning: Group compat-libraries does not have any packages to install.
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update

yum groupinstall "Compatibility Libraries" --setopt=group_package_types=mandatory,default,optional

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
There is no installed groups file.
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Warning: Group compat-libraries does not have any packages to install.
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update

uname -a
Linux 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 7 19:30:37 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
```

trying to install intel parallel studio, it complains *this product requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems... libstdc++ (including libstdc++6); without these libraries the compiler will not function properly.*

What is the proper solution to making sure 32-bit **everything** is available, on an already running RHEL/CentOS 7 system, so I don't have to deal with this nonsense?

the following did **NOT** help

```
I have done

subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms

yum install compat-libstdc++ 
yum install compat-libstdc++-33
yum install compat-gcc-44
yum install compat-gcc-44-c++
yum install compat-gcc-44-gfortran
```

Comment: Wrong syntax.  Try `yum install glibc-devel.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel Parallel Studio needs the 32-bit libraries.

```
yum install libgcc*i686 libstdc++*i686 glibc*i686 libgfortran*i686
```